# Tensorflow is not calculating the weights properly?

Tags: tensorflow

I was coding in tensorflow where input is equal to output so weight should be 1 and bias zero. But it is not giving proper result

the code is given bellow

```
import tensorflow as tf
x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,1])
y_=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,1])
W=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1,1]))
b=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
y=tf.matmul(x,W)+b
init=tf.global_variables_initializer()
cross_entropy=tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_,logits=y)
train_step=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.6).minimize(cross_entropy)
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(init)
for e in range(100):
    sess.run([train_step,cross_entropy],feed_dict={x:[[1],[2]],y_:[[1],[2]]})
print(sess.run([W,b]))
```

Comment: You shouldn't initialize your network to be all zeros. Search for "symmetry breaking" here. http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/

Comment: Can you describe little more? I have initialized with tf.global_variables_initializer() and set all the variable zero before